# How can i verify if the text on the button is correct in selenium using C#

Tags: c#, selenium

i need to verify if the text on my button is correct? How can i get the text on the button in selenium using C#. Thanks

Comment: There must be an attribute "value" for the button tag. You can fetch it using the **[getAttribute method](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebElement_GetAttribute.htm)**  Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks for the answer actually i get it now using this method.
`public static T GetAttributeAsType<T>(this IWebElement element, string attributeName)
        {
            string value = element.GetAttribute(attributeName) ?? string.Empty;
            return (T)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromString(value);
        }`